# Sort text based on last 3rd character

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I am using the sorted() function to sort the text based on last character
which works perfectly

```
def sort_by_last_letter(strings):
    def last_letter(s):
        return s[-1]
    return sorted(strings,key=last_letter)

print(sort_by_last_letter(["hello","from","last","letter","a"]))
```

Output

```
['a', 'from', 'hello', 'letter', 'last']
```

My requirement is to sort based on last 3rd character .But problem is few of the words are less than 3 character in that case it should be sorted based on next lower placed character (2 if present else last).Searching to do it in pythonic way

Presently I am getting

***IndexError: string index out of range***

```
def sort_by_last_letter(strings):
    def last_letter(s):
        return s[-3]
    return sorted(strings,key=last_letter)

print(sort_by_last_letter(["hello","from","last","letter","a"]))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
return sorted(strings,key=lambda x: x[max(0,len(x)-3)])
```

So thus we first calculate the length of the string `len(x)` and subtract `3` from it. In case the string is not that long, we will thus obtain a negative index, but by using `max(0,..)` we prevent that and thus take the last but one, or the last character in case these do not exist.

This will work given every string has at least one character. This will produce:

```
>>> sorted(["hello","from","last","letter","a"],key=lambda x: x[max(0,len(x)-3)])
['last', 'a', 'hello', 'from', 'letter']
```

In case you **do not care about tie-breakers** (in other words if `'a'` and `'abc'` can be reordered), you can use a more elegant approach:

```
from operator import itemgetter

return sorted(strings,key=itemgetter(slice(-3,None)))
```

What we here do is generating a slice with the last three characters, and then compare these substrings. This then generates:

```
>>> sorted(strings,key=itemgetter(slice(-3,None)))
['a', 'last', 'hello', 'from', 'letter']
```

Since we compare with:

```
   ['a', 'last', 'hello', 'from', 'letter']
#  ['a',  'ast',   'llo',  'rom',    'ter'] (comparison key)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the minimum of the string length and 3:

```
def sort_by_last_letter(strings):
    def last_letter(s):
        return s[-min(len(s), 3)]
    return sorted(strings,key=last_letter)

print(sort_by_last_letter(["hello","from","last","letter","a"]))
```

Comment: worked got ['last', 'a', 'hello', 'from', 'letter'] . , more intuitive answer would have been [' 'a',last', 'hello', 'from', 'letter']  as I didn't mention specifically in my question your solution works